# Image same height as width and hover div with text

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a solution to create an image hover effect and keeping the image same height as widht at the same time. Here is my code right now:

```css
.kozossegitag {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 100%;
 background: url(http://www.kaptarcoworking.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/koren_miklos.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden
}

.reszletek {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 100;
 background-color: rgba(67,85,103,0.7);
 opacity: 0;
}

.kozossegitag:hover .reszletek {
    background-color: rgba(67,85,103,0.5);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="kozossegitag">
<div class="reszletek">
<span>Koren Miklós</span>
</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to cover the whole image with this pastel blue color and place the text right on the image. As you see here (the left one is without hover, the right one is with):

[image]

Many thanks for every help!

Cheers,
Pepe

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.kozossegitag:hover{
    background-color: lightblue;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;    
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lonq5a8j/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not overly neat, as it's a little rushed but you get the idea. I used position absolute and some pseudo elements to create what I think you're trying to achieve.

### **CSS:**

```
.kozossegitag {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(http://www.kaptarcoworking.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/koren_miklos.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

/* give the div the ratio height */
.kozossegitag::after {
    content: "";
    padding-top: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.reszletek {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.kozossegitag:hover .reszletek {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

/* overlay the light blue using ::before */
.kozossegitag:hover::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(67, 85, 103, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;   
    z-index: 0;
}
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lonq5a8j/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

By positioning `.kozossegitag` relatively, you can position `.reszletek` absolutely right over top of it by setting width and height to 100% and top and left to 0.

You also forgot to set height to 0 on `.kozossegitag` to keep it square;

```
.kozossegitag {
    height:0;
    position:relative;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    background: url(http://www.kaptarcoworking.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/koren_miklos.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden
}

.reszletek {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(67,85,103,0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.kozossegitag:hover .reszletek {
    background-color: rgba(67,85,103,0.5);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/rpafw24q/